# How to pass Cardinality Threshold value for Histogram in Deequ package?

Tags: apache-spark, histogram, amazon-deequ

By default the variable `DEFAULT_CARDINALITY_THRESHOLD` is set to 120 in Deequ. This is very low for our use case.

Can anyone please suggest if we can set this value to a higher number?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely set it to a larger number. However, you might run into memory issues for very large histograms.